# Passing the success message from one view page to another page using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS. I have the requirement like i want to pass the success message from one html page to another page and I want to print that success message.

Here is my angularJS controller code,

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/test/resources/rest/event/createEvent',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data:  $scope.event
            }).success(function (data){
                if(data.status.status == 200){
                    //alert("data.status.message:"+data.status.message);
                    $scope.message=data.status.message; 
                    $window.location.href = "/test/view/myEvents.html";
                }else{
                    $scope.message=data.status.message;
                }
            });
```

The success message is binded under the scope.message.Just i want to pass that message and need to get in another page to print.

Please help me

TIA...

Answer (score 1):

you can use $rootscope to pass messages from one controller to another or even better to emit an event, that's as easier as:

```
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/test/resources/rest/event/createEvent',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data:  $scope.event
        }).success(function (data){
            if(data.status.status == 200){
                //alert("data.status.message:"+data.status.message);
                $rootScope.message=data.status.message; 
                $location.path('YourRoute');
            }else{
                $scope.message=data.status.message;
            }
        });
```

you can also use a service, an event bus, etc. that really depends on your needs but the easier is to use rootscope.

**EDIT:**

you can reference directly to rootscope on a view using {{$root.message}} look at this fiddler for reference http://jsfiddle.net/3XT3F/10/

Comment: what's the syntax to print this $rootScope message in another page ?

Comment: scope inherits from rootscope, you just need to use curly brackets in the other view as {{message}}

Comment: if not found on the scope angular search in the parent scope and it will end up looking on rootscope

Comment: i tried out by defining {{ root.message }}. It's not displaying

Comment: try only with {{message}}

Comment: I tried by using {{ mesaage }} also. It's not printing.

Comment: You used single page to display the message but i want to display the message from  one html page to another html page.

Comment: I see you are using a $window.location.href  that will do a full page refresh, try to use $location and refer to your route (you need to use a route provider in you angular app)

Comment: if you don't the option of using a SPA pass your message using a querystring in the url like myEvents.html?m=this is my message